# How can I find the second constant to solve this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I'm trying to solve the following first order PDE:

$$3u_x+y^2u_y=\frac{x}{y}u$$

Applying the method of characteristics we have the following:

$$\frac{dx}{3}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{ydu}{xu}$$

It can easily be seen that by combining the first equality we can get our first constant : 
$$\frac{dx}{3}=\frac{dy}{y^2}\\=>\frac{x}{3}=-\frac{1}{y}+c_1\\=>\frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{y}=c_1$$

This is where I'm stuck. I can't think of a proper combination which will allow me to integrate and find the second constant I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Edit: In case it helps, the solution manual says the second constant is : 
$$c_2=\ln{u}-\frac{x^2}{6y}-\frac{x^3}{54}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the last equation and the first one
$$\frac x 3 dx= \frac yu du$$

Use the first constant of integration
$$\frac x3 +\frac 1y=K$$
$$\implies y=-\frac 1{(x/3-K)}$$
$$\frac x 3 dx=\frac {du}{u(K-x/3)}$$
$$\frac x 3(K-\frac x 3) dx=\frac {du}{u}$$
After integration
$$K\frac {x^2}6-\frac {x^3}{27}+C_2=\ln |u|$$
Substitute $K=\frac x3+\frac 1y$
You get the final answer you posted 
$$\frac {x^3}{54}+\frac {x^2}{6y}+C_2=\ln |u|$$

Comment: Can we really use the first constant to get the second one? Maybe I haven't solved much problems but I haven't seen this method yet.Will this give 2 linearly independent constants?  ( I hope I'm using the right terminology here)

Comment: Yes you can do that..you will get another constant

Comment: @JohnKatsantas I got your final answer ...